# Close burger menu after clicking on some link

Tags: javascript, hamburger-menu

I have some burger menu made with html and CSS with some links in it. That works fine. However, when I click on some link the menu won't close. I tried some JavaScript examples, but it didn't work.

I'm really bad at JavaScript and need help with this. The point is I need the menu closes when user click on any link. Thanks!

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" />
  <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <img class="logo" src="assets/logo_white.svg" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cards">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I *highly* recommend having the word 'Menu' to the right of the icon and please make sure you're not forcing a hidden menu except for on small screens. Desktop first, contract features/layouts for mobile users. Ignore the hype because if you do you'll deal with a *lot* less maintenance in the long term which frees you up to *expand* what you're doing instead and *that* is how a programmer is able to make more money.

Comment: How did you open menu? (with added class? some type of animation?..) 
You can do something like `document.querySelectorAll('.menu-wrap .menu a" ).forEach(e=>{ e.addEventListener('click', ()={*** rewind animation or remove class ***})})`

Comment: I use css for burger animation, no javascript and it works great. I have animated lines, and smooth color which spreads to the whole page. That menu is only for mobile version, desktop has normal, full version.

Answer (score -1):

So I assume you are having a single page application without page reloads. You could close your sidebar every time a user clicks any link. If you are using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(".menu").hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

Or if you would like to use vanilla JS:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for( var i=els.length; i--; ) {
  els[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
     // close your menu here
     document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
  );
}
```

If you are already using jQuery, stick with it. If not, go for the vanilla version.

Comment: I down-voted, not the OP. You ignored that the user asked a JavaScript question and responded with jQuery! Dumping another 70KB to fix a small problem is *not* programming, it's dooming the OP and their visitors to more bloat. Please be responsible when trying to help people.

Comment: Have edited the question and added the vanilla version

Comment: Better don't use `'a'` selector, better add more [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to prevent errors something like `'.menu-wrap .menu a'`

Comment: I think he wants to close the menu if the user clicks somewhere outside menu. e.g. at a footer link. Then the menu should close as well.

Comment: For click somewhere outside menu better use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159229/14135825) for detect all elements not only `a` __(what about `button`?)__

Comment: I tried both solutions, but it doesn't work. In mobile view whole menu expand accross page with logo and links. I want that menu closes when somebody clicks on any link in that menu (textual or social icons)